# macro in right click menu for all workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote several macro with SAP scripting and other features.
For few of my macros, i need to select a cell, and then run the macro.
All these macros are stored in a add in, hence all my macros are available on every workbook.
I would like to share my addin with my colleagues but I would like to make the macros available from the right click menu.

All pieces of code found here and elsewhere indicate to have a piece of code located in "thisworkbook" tab. Hence the custom right click menu is only available on a specified workbook.

Is it possible to have my macro stored in my add-in accesibble from right click menu for all workbook that I open/use ? like the macro ribbon ?

thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible to customize the context menus (right-click) using the RibbonUI framework.

Comment: Check out [Ron de Bruin's examples](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s6/win001.htm) on how you can modify the right click menu.